# Is it possible to fragment a vector into all different possible fragment combinations?

Tags: r

For example, I have a vector `c(1,2,3,4,5)`

There are different fragment combinations:

Combination 0: 1 2 3 4 5

Combination 1: 12345

Combination 2: 1234 5

Combination 3: 123 45

Combination 4: 12 345

Combination 5: 1 2345

Combination 6: 12 34 5

Combination 7: 12 3 45

Combination 8: 1 23 45

Combination 9: 15 23 4

Combination 10: 14 23 5

… and so on (there are a lot of combinations).

**While the order does not matter:** 14 23 5 is equivalent to 5 41 32 (**Hence, only one of these combinations is needed**).

Is there a way in R to fragment a vector into all different possible fragment combinations?

I would like the output to be a (obviously very long) nested list containing all different possible fragment combinations.

In case of combination 9 and 10:

```
list(
list(c(1,5), c(2,3), 4),
list(c(1,4), c(2,3), 5)
)

[[1]]
[[1]][[1]]
[1] 1 5

[[1]][[2]]
[1] 2 3

[[1]][[3]]
[1] 4


[[2]]
[[2]][[1]]
[1] 1 4

[[2]][[2]]
[1] 2 3

[[2]][[3]]
[1] 5
```

Comment: Perhaps this helps. `library(partitions);v1 <- 1:5);out <- lapply(listParts(length(v1)), unclass)`

Comment: Amazing! This is exactly what I was looking for. Thank you akrun and wilbert

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think akrun has the correct answer. Just a little typo:

```
library(partitions)
v1 <- 1:5
lapply(listParts(length(v1)), unclass)
```

Comment: Amazing! This is exactly what I was looking for. Thank you akrun and wilbert